How can I change the visibility of a relativelayout in RecyclerView inside Another activity
How can I change the visibility of this relativelayout progressBarRelativeLayout in this RecyclerViewAdopter inside another activity


package com.google.gemini;



import android.content.Context;

import android.media.Image;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ChatRVAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<ChatsModel> chatsModelArrayList;

    private Context context;

    private UserViewHolder userViewHolder;

    RelativeLayout progressBarRelativeLayout;

    

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> progressBarVisibility = new MutableLiveData<>();



public void setProgressBarVisibility(int visibility) {

    progressBarVisibility.setValue(visibility);

}



    public ChatRVAdopter(ArrayList<ChatsModel> chatsModelArrayList, Context context) {

        this.chatsModelArrayList = chatsModelArrayList;

        this.context = context;

    }



    @NonNull

    @Override

    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;

        switch (viewType){

            case 0:

            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_message_block, parent, false);

            return new UserViewHolder(view);

            

            case 1:

            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gemini_chat_message_block, parent, false);

            return new BotViewHolder(view); 

            

        }

        return null;

    }



    @Override

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ChatsModel chatsModel = chatsModelArrayList.get(position);

    switch (chatsModel.getSender()) {

        case "user":

            ((UserViewHolder) holder).userTextView.setText(chatsModel.getMessage());

            break;

        case "bot":

            ((BotViewHolder) holder).BotMessageTextView.setText(chatsModel.getMessage());

            if (progressBarRelativeLayout != null) {

        progressBarRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

            break;

        

    }

}

    

    @Override

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        switch (chatsModelArrayList.get(position).getSender()){

            case "user":

            return 0;

            

            case "bot":

            return 1;

            

            default:

            return -1;

        }

    }

    



    @Override

    public int getItemCount() {

        return chatsModelArrayList.size();

    }



    public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView userTextView;

    RelativeLayout progressBarRelativeLayout;



    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        userTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_chat_TextView);

        progressBarRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_RelativeLayout);

        

       

    }

}



    public static class BotViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView BotMessageTextView;

        RelativeLayout relatedTopicCoordinator, topicRelativeLayout;

        ImageView geminiBottomIcGoogle;



        public BotViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            BotMessageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gemini_response_chat_TextView);

            

            relatedTopicCoordinator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relatedTopic_Coordinator);

        geminiBottomIcGoogle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gemini_bottom_ic_google);

        topicRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.topic_RelativeLayout);

            

            

            geminiBottomIcGoogle.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                    

                        

                            if(topicRelativeLayout != null && topicRelativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                                topicRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }else{

                                topicRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }

                });

            

            

        }

    }

   

    

    public void showProgressBar() {

    // Change the visibility of the progress bar to VISIBLE

    if (userViewHolder != null) {

        userViewHolder.progressBarRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}



public void hideProgressBar() {

    // Change the visibility of the progress bar to GONE

    if (userViewHolder != null) {

        userViewHolder.progressBarRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

}

    

   



    

}



I tried this in another activity but it didn't hide the relativelayout that i wanted to hide
chatsModelArrayList.add(new ChatsModel(query, USER_KEY));
        chatRVAdopter.hideProgressBar();

            chatRVAdopter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Can you help me resolve the problem
